Spectrum of self-adjoint operator is the support of the corresponding spectral measure
I have the following question:

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and let $P_T$ be the corresponding projection-valued measure on $\mathbb R$. Show that $\sigma_T = \text{supp} P_T$, where
$$ \text{supp} P_T = \left(\bigcup \{ O \subseteq X : O \ \text{open}, P_T (O) = 0 \} \right)^c$$ 

I think I need to use the spectral theorem to solve this problem, but I don't really understand it. The theorem states that:
$$T = \int \lambda d P_T (\lambda)$$
How should I interpret this integral? Is this a Riemann-Stieljes integral? If for instance I have a vector $v$ or a set $E$, how does $Tv$ and $T(E)$ look like?
Thank you for all who can help.

This integral is given by the limit of the Riemann-Stieltjes sums in the operator norm. Thus, in its integral form, for any $v\in H$, $Tv$ is given by $\underset{\left|\Delta\right|\to0}{\lim}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}\lambda_j P_T\left(\left[x_{j-1},x_j\right)\right)v$, where $\Delta=\left(a=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_m=b\right)$ is a partition of (some interval $\left[a,b\right]$ which contains) $\sigma\left(T\right)$, $\lambda_j\in\left[x_{j-1},x_j\right)$, and $\left|\Delta\right|=\underset{i=1,\ldots,n}{\max}\left|x_i-x_{i-1}\right|$. More on this can be found for example in the book "Functional Analysis" by Peter Lax, or any other standard functional analysis textbook. As for $T\left(E\right)$, there is no interpretation of it which I am aware of. There is an interpretation of $\chi_E\left(T\right)$ (or of $f\left(T\right)$ for any $f:\sigma\left(T\right)$ which is Borel measurable).
As for your first question, let me use the fact that
\begin{equation}
\sigma\left(T\right)=\left\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}:\exists\left(\psi_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\|\psi_n\|=1\text{ and }\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\|T\psi_n-\lambda\psi_n\|=0\right\}.
\end{equation}
Then, if $\lambda\in\text{supp}\, P_T$, then for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $P_T\left(\lambda-\frac{1}{n},\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\right)\neq0$. Take any normalized $\psi\in\text{Ran}P_T\left(\lambda-\frac{1}{n},\lambda+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and show that $\|T\psi-\lambda\psi\|$ is small. This would imply that $\text{supp}\,P_T\subseteq\sigma\left(T\right)$. In the other direction, if $\lambda\notin\text{Supp}\,P_T$, then there exists $\eta>0$ such that $P_T\left(\left(\lambda-\eta,\lambda+\eta\right)\right)=0$. This implies that in the Riemann-Stieltjes sums, we can actually assume that $\left|\lambda_j-\lambda\right|\geq\eta$ for $j=0,\ldots,n$. Using this, for any sequence of normalized vectors $\left(\psi_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, we get
\begin{equation}
\|T\psi_n-\lambda\psi_n\|^2=\|\underset{\left|\Delta\right|\to0}{\lim}\sum\limits_{j=1}^m\lambda_jP_T\left(\left[x_{j-1},x_j\right)\right)\psi_n-\lambda\psi_n\|^2=\underset{\left|\Delta\right|\to0}{\lim}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}\left|\lambda_j-\lambda\right|\|P_T\left(\left[x_{j-1},x_j\right)\right)\psi_n\|^2\\\geq\eta\underset{\left|\Delta\right|\to0}{\lim}\sum\limits_{j=1}^m\|P_T\left(\left[x_{j-1},x_j\right)\right)\psi_n\|^2=\eta,
\end{equation}
and this implies that $\lambda\notin\sigma\left(T\right)$.
